# Angular material icon don't displayed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I started a new project based on Angular 17 and I use Angular Material for components but the icons are not displayed. I've already checked everything but I don't see where the problem comes from.
I added the CSS of the material library in the index.html but nothing. here an example of a page which integrates icons, and other files.

Homepage.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>Digisoft</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <span >{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}</span>

<!--  <i  class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>-->
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialogPass()">
      <mat-icon>webhook</mat-icon>
      <span>Change password</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialogEdit(person)">
      <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
      <span>Edit information</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="logOut()">
      <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
      <span>Deconnexion</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

homepage.ts

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogConfig} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {ChangePasswordDialogComponent} from "../../components/change-password-dialog/change-password-dialog.component";
import {EditDataDialogComponent} from "../../components/edit-data-dialog/edit-data-dialog.component";
import {MatToolbar, MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatButton, MatButtonModule, MatIconButton} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatIcon, MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatMenu, MatMenuItem, MatMenuModule, MatMenuTrigger} from "@angular/material/menu";
import {UserCreateFields} from "../../../auth-api/src-api/models/UserType/user-create-fields";
import {AuthService} from "../../../services/authService/auth.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {SliderComponent} from "../../components/slider/slider.component";
import {faArrowLeft} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {FontAwesomeModule} from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    SliderComponent,
    MatMenuItem,
    MatMenu,
    MatToolbar,
    MatIconButton,
    MatIcon,
    MatMenuTrigger,
  ],
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home-page.component.scss'
})
export class HomePageComponent {

  slides: any[] = [
    {
      url: '../../../assets/image/img_3.svg',
      title: 'IT Development Company',
      description: 'Your partner for innovative solutions',
      link: '#atouts',
      linkContent: 'Nos atouts',
    },
    {
      url: '../../../assets/image/img_2.svg',
      title: 'Hosting and Maintenance',
      description: '',
      link: '#heb-main',
      linkContent: 'Details',
    },
    {
      url: '../../../assets/image/img_1.svg',
      title: 'Web development',
      description: '',
      link: '#dev-web',
      linkContent: 'Details',
    },
    {
      url: '../../../assets/image/img.svg',
      title: 'Mobile Development',
      description: '',
      link: '#dev-mob',
      linkContent: 'Details',
    },
  ];
  constructor( private authService:AuthService,
               private router:Router,
               private dialog: MatDialog,) {

  }

  currentIndex = 0;

  nextSlide() {
    this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) % 4;
  }

  prevSlide() {
    this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex - 1 + 4) % 4;
  }

  person: UserCreateFields = {email: "", lastName:"fdfd", firstName: "dfdf", password: ""}

  openDialogPass() {
    this.dialog.open(ChangePasswordDialogComponent, {
      height: '90%',
      width: '30%',
      disableClose:false,
    });
  }
  openDialogEdit(person: any) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.height = '75%';
    dialogConfig.width = '90%';

    dialogConfig.data= {
      person: person,
    };

    this.dialog.open(EditDataDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDataDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data=="ok"){

          // this.userService.findByEmail(person.email).subscribe(value => {
          //   this.person = value
          // })
        }
      }
    );
    dialogRef.close();

  }

  logOut() {

    // this.dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent, {
    //   disableClose:false,
    //   data:{
    //     message: "Voulez-vous quitter l'application ?"
    //   }
    // }).afterClosed().subscribe(value => {
    //   if (value=='oui'){
    //     this.authenservice.disconect();
    //     this.router.navigate(['']);
    //   }
    // });

  }

  protected readonly faArrowLeft = faArrowLeft;
}
```

style.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "styles/themeProp";
//@import "styles/custom-theme";
/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";


@import "styles/reset";
html, body { height: 100%;}
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

.form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.field {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-card{
  border: 1rem #ff4081;
}
.grid{
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}

.mat-input-element, .mat-form-field, .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  //max-width: 600px;
}
.btn-out{
  color: #3f51b5;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth-landing-page",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "auth-api": " npm run auth-api:openDocApi3-gen",
    "auth-api:openDocApi3-gen": "ng-openapi-gen --input src/auth-api/documentation/swagger.json --output src/auth-api/src-api"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng-openapi-gen": "^0.51.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tinymce": "^6.7.3",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "authLandingPage": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/auth-landing-page",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/custom-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "authLandingPage:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "authLandingPage:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "authLandingPage:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AuthLandingPage</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for mat-icon has changed.

https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples

You should be doing this instead:

```
<mat-icon fontIcon="webhook"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: it work when i put icon offside the button but when it is in the button it don't work

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Material icon stylesheet is included in the index.html, if not you need to add it manually.